# callback function of FB.getLoginStatus cannot be fired when user is not in 'login' status in facebook website

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my website, I have code as:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        // if login Facebook already
    } else {
        // if not login yet
    }
});
```

callback function will be fired when user logged in on Facebook website. But if user logout on Facebook website. That callback function will not be fired! Does anyone has same problem ever?  Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

this is becuase getLoginStatus will only be invoked once when it is called.

to get a call fcn to be fired when the user logout, you should subscribe to the correasponding event by using FB.Event.subscribe

Events
JavaScript apps are typically written with heavy use of events, and the SDK encourages this by exposing various events. These are fired by the various interactions with authentication flows, such as FB.login() or Login button. Widgets such as Comments plugin may also trigger authentication.

auth.login
This event is fired when your app first notices the user (in other words, gets a session when it didn't already have a valid one).

auth.logout
This event is fired when your app notices that there is no longer a valid user (in other words, it had a session but can no longer validate the current user).

auth.authResponseChange
This event is fired for any auth related change as they all affect the session: login, logout, session refresh. Sessions are refreshed over time as long as the user is active with your app.

for details, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the event of the user signing out, you can add an event like so:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
  // do something with response
});
```

Additionally you can do that:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
   // user is now logged out
});
```